# Using OpenDDS with Qt6

Tags: c++, qt, opendds

Can someone guide me on how to use OpenDDS with Qt6? I need to make a Chatroom application on Qt with the help of OpenDDS and I can't find any learning material for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenDDS has [a demo](https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/tree/DDS-3.19/examples/DCPS/ishapes) used to demonstrate interoperability with other DDS implementations that uses Qt that could serve as an example. It's Qt 5 though, we haven't updated it to Qt 6 yet. There's also some more information about OpenDDS and Qt listed [here](https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/blob/DDS-3.19/docs/qt.md).

Comment: I will go through those examples for sure. Thanks for the help.